# Deserialization of Byte Array using C#

Tags: c#, deserialization, binary-data

I have here the codes where I use for Serialization or binary code, now What I need to do is to deserialize the binary code but I have no idea how to deserialize the binary code. 
Can anyone help me out? Thanks

```
byte[] bytes;
string[] tempDataColumnValue = null;
List<string> stringArray = new List<string>();
int pointNum = 1;
string x = "25000";
string y = "-36000";
stringArray.Add(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", pointNum, x, y));
tempDataColumnValue = stringArray.ToArray();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(stream, tempDataColumnValue);
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
}

string insertSql = "INSERT INTO [DefMngDBReportTemp] ([AuthorityKey],[DBReport],[TempData]) VALUES ('0qfnux45blxwbkjx2iah33ym','一筆印刷図','" + bytes.ToString() + "')";
string connstr = "Password=sonicweb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=AigsDemo50;Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS";
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
sqlconn.Open();

SqlCommand sqlquery = new SqlCommand(insertSql, sqlconn);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I assume you are having some problems with the obvious `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` method that couldn't be solved with the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Before you worry about deserializing, you should really address the HUGE issues with your serialization code. All your database records will contain "System.Byte[]" in the TempData field, which is clearly not intended.

Comment: Also is that really actually storing things correctly? It looks like it will store "System.Byte[]" which is what `bytes.ToString()` is likely to return... You might want to take a step back and ask how to store binary data in a database. You might also want to take a further step back and consider why you are converting string data to binary data before storing it in a database.

Comment: @Chris yes, unfortunately, im having problems with BinaryFormatter.Deserialize method.. The output I need is to be an array that is comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
var obj = bf.Deserialize(bytes) as String[];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BinaryFormatter class too.
You can se documentation [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)